# How to include a UI binder widget into another UI binder widget

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am trying to include a UI binder widget into another one: I am building a form with UI binder and would like to include a fancy button done also with UI binder. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.  Something like:

```
<gwt:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:gwt='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:foo='url:import:com.foo.your.package.here'>
  <gwt:HTMLPanel>
    <foo:YourUiBinderStuff />
  </gwt:HTMLPanel>
</gwt:UiBinder>
```